# setting a virtual resolution in wayland

Tags: linux, wayland

Is it possible to set a virtual resolution of a screen, meaning increasing its resolution over its normal resolution (say, I've got a 1920x1080 screen, can I use it like it was a 3640x2160 screen)?
With X it was easy, just xrandr --scale 2x2, but with wayland I can't seem to find a way to do it...

It would be to set up a multi-screen environment, with one good screen and a bad screen, and I need to double the resolution of the bad screen, to have the windows about the same size in both screens, which is my goal.
I've read somewhere about multi-screen scaling, but couldn't fine more informations about

Thank you for your help

Comment: This question and wayland are a year older and the best answers to this question I could find was to deactivate wayland. Seriously? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using weston compositor then you can specify the "scale" factor in weston.ini file under [ouput] section please refer here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/weston.ini.5.html

> scale=factor
>
> The scaling multiplier applied to the entire output, in support of high resolution("HiDPI"  or "retina") displays, that roughly corresponds to the pixel ratio of the display's physical resolution to the logical resolution.  Applications that do  not support  high resolution displays typically appear tiny and unreadable. Weston will scale the output of such applications by this multiplier, to  make  them  readable.Applications  that  do  support  their own output scaling can draw their content in high resolution, in which case they avoid compositor scaling. Weston will not scale the output of such applications, and they are not affected by this multiplier.
>   An integer, 1 by default, typically configured as 2 or higher when needed, denoting
>   the scaling multiplier for the output.